# Check result of transaction before updating table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[vRpt_VolunteerPaymentsAll]
@startdate DATETIME = NULL ,
@enddate DATETIME = NULL ,
@user NVARCHAR(50)
AS /*  This procedure generates Team Events that have been audtied  */
DECLARE @sd DATETIME
DECLARE @ed DATETIME

/* Ensure that the start and end dates covert whole days */
SET @sd = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @startdate, 120) + ' 00:00:00'
SET @ed = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @enddate, 120) + ' 23:59:59'



DECLARE @id INT

INSERT  INTO vVolunteerPaymentEvents
        ( StartDate ,
          EndDate ,
          Verifier ,
          DatePaid ,
          RecordsPaid ,
          UnDone ,
          Comments ,
          Flags
        )
VALUES  ( @startdate ,
          @enddate ,
    /*Get the users initials*/
          ( SELECT  dbo.vUsers.Initials
            FROM    dbo.vUsers
            WHERE   dbo.vUsers.UserID = @user
          ) ,
          GETDATE() ,
    /* Count how many records are going ot be affected*/
          ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    dbo.vVolunteerPayments
            WHERE   dbo.vVolunteerPayments.PaymentEventID = 0
                    AND ( dbo.vVolunteerPayments.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd
                                                          AND
                                                          @ed )
          ) ,
          0 ,
          '' ,
          0
        )
/*Set the id of the payment event id for the volunteer payments*/
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() ;

--get the totals for the payment based on the 
--@id value just inserted above 
UPDATE  dbo.vVolunteerPayments
SET     dbo.vVolunteerPayments.PaymentEventID = @id ,
        dbo.vVolunteerPayments.DatePaid = GETDATE()
WHERE   dbo.vVolunteerPayments.PaymentEventID = 0
        AND dbo.vVolunteerPayments.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd
                                               AND     @ed

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT  VOLSACCT.volunteerid ,
        ISNULL(VOLS.Forename, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(VOLS.Surname, '') AS Name ,
        VOLSACCT.SortCode ,
        VOLSACCT.AccountName ,
        VOLSACCT.AccountNumber ,
        SUM(CASE [Type]
              WHEN 1001
              THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed

                             --AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
                             --AND PMTS.VolunteerId = @volunteerid
                        THEN Amount
                   END
              ELSE 0
            END) AS Reimbursements ,
        SUM(CASE [Type]
              WHEN 1002
              THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed

                             --AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
                             --AND PMTS.VolunteerId = @volunteerid
                        THEN Amount
                   END
              ELSE 0
            END) AS MobilePhoneCharges ,
        SUM(CASE [Type]
              WHEN 1003
              THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
                             --AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
                             --AND PMTS.VolunteerId = @volunteerid
                        THEN Amount
                   END
              ELSE 0
            END) AS GPContributions ,
        SUM(CASE [Type]
              WHEN 12
              THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
                             --AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
                             --AND PMTS.VolunteerId = @volunteerid
                        THEN Amount
                   END
              ELSE 0
            END) AS GPExpenses ,
        SUM(CASE [Type]
              WHEN 137
              THEN CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
                             --PaymentEventID = 0
                             --AND PMTS.VolunteerId = @volunteerid
                        THEN Amount
                   END
              ELSE 0
            END) AS Expenses ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed

                      --AND PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
                      --AND PMTS.VolunteerId = @volunteerid
                       THEN Mileage
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS TotalMileageWeek ,
        VOLSACCT.BACS,
        PMTS.ChargeRate

FROM    dbo.vVolunteerPayments PMTS
        INNER JOIN dbo.vVolunteerAccounts VOLSACCT ON PMTS.VolunteerId = VOLSACCT.VolunteerID
        INNER JOIN dbo.vVolunteers VOLS ON PMTS.VolunteerId = VOLS.VolunteerID
WHERE   PMTS.PaymentEventID = @id
GROUP BY VOLSACCT.volunteerid ,
        VOLSACCT.AccountName ,
        VOLSACCT.AccountNumber ,
        VOLSACCT.BACS ,
        VOLSACCT.SortCode ,
        VOLS.Forename ,
        VOLS.Surname,
        PMTS.ChargeRate) AS A
        WHERE 
        GPContributions >0
        OR GPExpenses > 0
        OR MobilePhoneCharges > 0
        OR Expenses > 0
        OR Reimbursements > 0 
        OR Expenses > 0
        OR TotalMileageWeek >0
        ORDER BY Name
```

It basically inserts a summary record of affected transactions into one table (volunteerpaymentevent) , updates existing records of another table (volunteerpayments(datepaid and payment event id)) and then returns record sets of sumary values within a join

However I have found that if the join fails or there are no joins at all (and consequently nothing outputs) then the update part of the procedure still updates the records

Is there a way of checking the result of the  inner join before updating the records in the volunteerpayments table
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside a transaction:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[vRpt_VolunteerPaymentsAll]
@startdate DATETIME = NULL ,
@enddate DATETIME = NULL ,
@user NVARCHAR(50)
AS 

begin transaction

your procedure code

commit transaction
```

See [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) for more on transactions.

Comment: And for the second part (if your join is null), you could select a count of records from the joined table and then if returns zero records, run `rollback transaction`.